# Ejercicio Javascript

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, condiciones

¿Cómo puedo mostrar el último `alert` del programa solo cuando se han introducido 3 veces mal los datos?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            for(var i=1;i<=3;i++) {
                var identificador=prompt("Introduzca su identificador");
                var contrasena=prompt("Introduzca su contraseña");

                if(identificador=='user' && contrasena=='123') {
                    alert('Los datos son correctos');
                    break;
                }else{
                    alert('Los datos son incorrectos');
                }   
                alert('Intentos agotados');
            }    
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola User. qué es lo que has intentado para resolverlo ?  Necesitamos conocer tu problema concreto porque nosotros no resolvemos tareas/ejercicios si no dudas y errores particulares. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo!

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que usar un contador e ir sumandole 1 cada vez que haga un error y con un condicional comprobar si ha llegado al numero máximo de errores.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">


var cont =1;
for(var i=1;i<=3;i++) {
    var identificador=prompt("Introduzca su identificador");
    var contrasena=prompt("Introduzca su contraseña");

if(identificador=='user' && contrasena=='123') {
        alert('Los datos son correctos');
        break;
    }else{
        cont++;
        alert('Los datos son incorrectos');
    }   
    if (cont >= 3) 
       alert('Intentos agotados');
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ya casi lo tienes, solo una pequeña corrección: saca el último `alert` **fuera** de tu `for( )`, y comprueba cuantos intentos has realizado:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head> 
<body>
<script>
for( var i = 0; i <= 3; ++i ) {
  var identificador = prompt( "Introduzca su identificador" );
  var contrasena = prompt( "Introduzca su contraseña" );

  if(identificador == 'user' && contrasena == '123' ) {
    alert( 'Los datos son correctos' );
    break;
  }else{
   alert( 'Los datos son incorrectos' );
  }   
}

if( i == 3 ) alert( 'Intentos agotados' );

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Esto solo es posible porque **has utilizado `var` para tus variables**. Si hubieras usado `let`, entonces ya sería otra historia :-)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar una variable booleana y cambiar su estado si el usario ingresa la informacion correcta.  Algo asi:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var success = false;
for(var i=1;i<=3;i++) {
    var identificador=prompt("Introduzca su identificador");
    var contrasena=prompt("Introduzca su contraseña");

if(identificador=='user' && contrasena=='123') {
        success = true;
        alert('Los datos son correctos');
        break;
    }else{
        alert('Los datos son incorrectos');
    }   
    
}

if (!success) {
  alert('Intentos agotados');
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```